# Unable to create an object of type 'Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, asp.net-core

I tried to create a new Database using `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext` and got this error: Unable to create an object of type 'Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728. The Build is successful, but than it fails with that error message. I use Sqlite for my databases. Here is my code:

Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Sooziales_Netzwerk.Models;

namespace Sooziales_Netzwerk.Data{

public class Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext : DbContext
{
    public Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext(DbContextOptions<Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Link> Link {get; set;}
}
}
```

Link.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Sooziales_Netzwerk.Models;

public class Link{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int idLink {get; set;}

[Display(Name = "Enter Link")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Upload without a link make no sence")]
public string link {get; set;}

[Display(Name = "Enter Username")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Upload without a link make no sence")]
public string username {get; set;}

[Display(Name = "Enter Likes")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Upload without a link make no sence")]
public int likes {get; set;}
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Sooziales_Netzwerk.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Try to add `-v` argument to get verbose logs

Comment: @Artur https://pastebin.com/KFJ5DtcN

Comment: @Qing Guo is actually right, you are missing `Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext` registration in DI. You are registering `ApplicationDbContext` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LinkConnection")));
```

And this to appsettings.json:

```
    "LinkConnection": "DataSource=links.db"
```

Answer (score 1):

1.add below code code in Program.cs :

```
builder.services.AddDbContext<Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection1"]));
```

2. added a connection string to the appsettings.json file in `"ConnectionStrings"`: like below:

   ```
     "DefaultConnection1": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext -7dc5b790-765f-4381-988c-5167405bb107;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   ```

Comment: That didnt work. I use Sqlite to manage the databases, so I cant use option.UseSqlServer(). But thanks for you answer.

Comment: Thanks. Found the code for Sqlite.